# How to get the defined Contact Groups on an Android?

Tags: android, contacts

I would like to get a list of Contacts Groups already defined in the system, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the [Contacts.Group](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/Contacts.Groups.html) table for the available groups.

You can use the [Contacts.GroupMembership](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/Contacts.GroupMembership.html) table to query what group a particular contact is a member of. `PERSON_ID` is the ID of the contact, `GROUP_ID` matches the ID of the group.

Note that both these APIs have been deprecated in favour of [ContactsContract.Groups](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Groups.html) and [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.html) from 2.0 onwards.

Comment: I don't see any method on the first link, to get the Groups, only some constants. Also can I create programmatically new groups? Do you know any tutorial or example for the first class(1.6)?

Comment: You need to use the ContentResolver.query() method to query the table. See: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html This has info on programatically inserting new entries into a table too.

Comment: Do you happen to know the URI for the SDK 2.0+ to insert to?